# What is the main tag in HTML5 ? How does it differ from body tag?

Tags: html

I have a lot of confusion around `main` tag of HTML. It describes content of the page but so does `body`. There should be only one `main` tag in the page. The `body` tag should also have one appearance in HTML. What is the difference between these two tags ? Which elements can be nested between `main` tag and which can't? How does this tag change it's nature to flow content and palpable content ?

Comment: body is everything, main is the main content. Navigation for example is not main content. Footer is not main content... and so on.

Comment: Take a look at [main](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main)

Comment: Or look at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_main.asp , which is what a simple search brought to light as first result.

Comment: Well, then any other of the first 500 results of any given search on the web.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [edit] the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the **[ask]** page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?ei=cwQWXa2APIeS8gKqwI-gAg&q=html5+main+tag+how+to+use+it) and [Bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=how+to+use+the+main+tag+in+HTML5) should help you, also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477804/how-to-correctly-use-the-html5-main-element)

Comment: An important point taken from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main) is: <main> doesn't contribute to the document's outline; that is, unlike elements such as <body>, headings such as <h2>, and such, <main> doesn't affect the DOM's concept of the structure of the page. It's strictly informative.

Answer (score 23):

According to W3, differences between main and body:

[**main**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_main.asp):

> The content inside the **main** element should be unique to the
> document. It should not contain any content that is repeated across
> documents such as sidebars, navigation links, copyright information,
> site logos, and search forms.

[**body**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_body.asp):

> The **body** element contains all the contents of an HTML document, such
> as text, hyperlinks, images, tables, lists, etc.

An easy example, the footer element; you should put it inside the body, but outside the main, as you will do with your menu, or sidebar.